# How can I convert IQueryable<T> to ObjectQuery<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, iqueryable, eager-loading, objectquery

I'm trying to apply the advice in this post: [Tip 22 - How to make Include really Include](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx)

It suggests a workaround for ensure eager loading works in the Entity Framework (4.2). That workaround involves casting the IQueryable to an ObjectQuery.

However, when I attempt this, as shown in the post, the query returns a null.

My query is (ctx is a DbContext):

```
IEnumerable<Coupon> coupons =
    from x in ctx.Coupons
    where x.LanguageCode.Equals("EN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.CategoryId == MainCategoryId && x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate
    select x;
```

That works as expected.

However, when I use,

```
IEnumerable<Coupon> coupons =
    (from x in ctx.Coupons
     where x.LanguageCode.Equals("EN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.CategoryId == MainCategoryId && x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate
     select x) as ObjectQuery<Coupon>;
```

it assigns a null to "coupons".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What if you use `var` instead of `IEnumerable<Coupon>`?  `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are not the same thing.

Comment: Is your ctx a DbContext or an ObjectContext? ObjectQuerys are only used with ObjectContexts. You can also inspect coupons.GetType() in the debugger, to see what type the query really is.

Comment: Thanks. I've update the post to say I'm using a DBContext.

Comment: In that case, the only answer can be "You cannot convert an `IQueryable<T>` to an `ObjectQuery<T>` unless that `IQueryable<T>` really is an `ObjectQuery<T>`." I'm wondering why you really need that, though. In your query, you wouldn't need the workaround in the first place, but if you did, does `(from x in ctx.Coupons ... select x).Include(...)` not do the trick, assuming you're `using System.Data.Entity;`?

Comment: @Hvd. Thanks. I didn't have System.Data.Entity in the using declarations and was relying on Intellisense to determine what was allowed - so didn't think I could use .Include there! And then got into reading an old blog post that "confirmed" that misconception. Doh! Shouldn't code when tired and frustrated, I guess. If you want to post an answer, I'll then accept it - or I'll self-answer in a few days, referencing your comment.

Comment: @dommer Thanks, I've posted it as an answer. Glad to read it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments to an answer:

Casting to an `ObjectQuery<T>` only works when the query really is an `ObjectQuery<T>`, it won't work on any other `IQueryable<T>`. Since you're using a `DbContext` instead of an `ObjectContext`, the queries are of a different type. However, you do not need to cast to the correct type, the `DbExtensions.Include` extension methods in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace accept any `IQueryable<T>` type, and call the appropriate underlying `Include` method. You can use this, avoid the cast, and thereby avoid explicitly specifying the query's type in your code.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is equivalent to this

```
IEnumerable<Coupon> coupons =
    from x in ctx.Coupons
    where x.LanguageCode.Equals("EN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.CategoryId == MainCategoryId && x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate
    select x;

ObjectQuery<Coupon> converted = coupons as ObjectQuery<Coupon>;
```

, with `coupons` not null and `converted` null.

Which means the cast is failing.
This does not solve your problem, but at least identifies it.

Perhaps you are using a different version of Entity Framework?

Comment: Thanks. It could indeed be that this workaround no longer applies, as the post was in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting the SQL Query From an Entity Framework IQueryable](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/07/getting-the-sql-query-from-an-entity-framework-iqueryable/) helped me solve this issue to satisfy a slightly different requirement, I need to access the TraceString *AND* the underlying parameters so I could inject a few `IQueryable<>` expressions into a `.SqlQuery<>()`

> When you inspect an `IQueryable` during a debug session you can see that internally it uses ObjectQuery, but it does not *Inherit* from ObjectQuery so you cannot cast it directly. We can however use Reflection to access the internal query object.

Here's Steve Fenton's code wrapped into an Extension Method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extract the Internal Object Query from an IQueryable, you might do this to access the internal parameters for logging or injection purposes
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Sourced from https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/07/getting-the-sql-query-from-an-entity-framework-iqueryable/ </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Entity Type that is the target of the query</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">The query to inspect</param>
    /// <returns>Object Query that represents the same IQueryable Expression</returns>
    public static System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T> ToObjectQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        // force the query to be cached, otherwise parameters collection will be empty!
        string queryText = query.ToString();
        queryText = queryText.ToLower(); // stop compiler from optimising this code away because we don't do anything with queryText parameter!

        var internalQueryField = query.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("InternalQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
        var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(query);
        var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
        return objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>;
    }
```

Now your code can look like this:

```
IEnumerable<Coupon> coupons =
    (from x in ctx.Coupons
     where x.LanguageCode.Equals("EN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.CategoryId == MainCategoryId && x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate
     select x).ToObjectQuery();
```